# How to exclude resources from my maven build, packagingExcludes not working

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am using the **maven-war-plugin** to build a .war file

I am using packagigExcludes and it is working fine for .jar files:

```
 <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/jetty-*.ja                        
                        WEB-INF/../resources/log4j.properties,
                        WEB-INF/../resources/web.properties
                    </packagingExcludes>
```

But the properties files above are not getting exluded, I also tried:

```
src/main/resources/web.properties
```

This is a multi-module maven project, and I am building a .war file for this spring mvc maven project and I have to exclude these files but it isn't working.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i just tried ... are you sure you're doing the configuration in the right place? my pom looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>example-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>example-webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
       [...]
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>example-webapp</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

----> EDIT

to exlude stuff from resource, you would have to do this:

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>
                        WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties
                    </packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: But your not even trying to exclude a resource from the /resources folder? like web.properties in my example.  .jar files are working for me also.

Comment: yes - but take care! the resources are not actually in resources ... stuff from /src/main/resources foes into /WEB-INF/classes/ so you might want to exlude      <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</packagingExcludes>

Comment: instead. the solution below stops those files from being copied in the first place (from src to target) so it would probably work as well.

Comment: so it worked, expect for a something.json file, I can't explain why it doesn't work with a .json file, but with properties it worked.  I just did:  `WEB-INF/classes/*.properties, WEB-INF/classes/*.json`

Answer (score 2):

Add this in `pom.xml`

```
</build>
  <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>web.properties</exclude>
            </excludes
        </resource>
  </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention, I am using the maven-war-plugin to build a .war file, should I still try that?

Comment: well, the original approach still works, if you keep in mind that the contents of src/main/resources is copied to ${target}/WEB-INF/classes/ so you have to exclude those paths, not the paths in the source folder.

Comment: @malchow it is producing a .war file though, so that folder doesn't really exist until it is exploded.

Comment: @JigarJoshi didn't work, when I unzipped the .war file it still contains the files in the resource folder in the /classes folder.